# Grabbing specific data from json

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
        const URL = ["https://api.covid19api.com/summary"];
        let global = await fetch(URL);
        let data = await global.json();


        const COVID_EMBED = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle(`__**Global COVID-19 Status Tracker:**__`)
        .setDescription(`Placeholder_description.`)
        .addField(`Newly Confirmed Cases: `, data.Global.NewConfirmed, true)
        .addField(`Total Confirmed Cases: `, data.Global.TotalConfirmed, true)
        .addField(`New Deaths: `, data.Global.NewDeaths, true)
        .addField(`Total Deaths: `, data.Global.TotalDeaths, true)
        .addField(`Newly Recovered Cases: `, data.Global.NewRecovered, true)
        .addField(`Total Recovered Cases: `, data.Global.TotalRecovered, true)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor(0)
 return message.channel.send ({embed: COVID_EMBED });
```

I am making a covid command.

Above is the code to fetch the "global" cases etc, though the URL, [here](https://api.covid19api.com/summary) also has specific countries, how would I fetch a specific country? so instead of `data.Global.NewRecovered` what would I change that to fetch "Greece" For example?

Comment: You are trying just to get data of single country ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided json response, there is a list of Countries. Javascript can use [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search through the list if you want a specific one, like Greece:

```
let greeceStatistics = data.Countries.find(countryData => countryData.CountryCode === "GR");
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was easier than expected. Though implementing it into the embed gives me an undefined.. Any clue as to why?

Comment: Just replace data.Global with greeceStatistics. If still doesn't work, update your question and show how are you doing it.

Comment: yeah no that's correct, there was an error on my behalf. It's been fixed! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you could use filter , by country name :

JS code , JSON data named `covidData`

```
function countryData(countryName){
        let res = covidData.Countries.filter(countrie=>countrie.Country===countryName)
    return res
}

//console.log(countryData('Greece'))
```